# Append input text field for search function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jquery code right now. 
This is meant to be a search function eventually, right now i got my animation, but i am yet to add an input text field to the function that i can use for my C# code for the search function. This should emerge after the border expands and dissapear when the user clicks on the html, just like the script does to the border.

```
    $(function () {
        var search = $("#search");

        search.click(function () {
            search.attr("src", "Icons/magnifier.png").css({ "border": "2px", "border-style": "solid", "border-color": "#808080", "padding-left": "130px", "transition": "all 500ms" });
        });
        $('html').click(function (e) {
            if (e.target.id != 'search') {
                $("#search").attr("src", "Icons/magnifier2.png");
                $("#search").removeAttr('style');;
            }
        });
    })
```

I guess i have to make an appendto function, but im still unsure how to create it in such a way that when the user press enter it fires the search function.

Right now however, i just want to create the textfield, so that it can be used in the further process.

https://jsfiddle.net/ymzzpLdd/

Comment: I think if you're building the animation first and then the input and the actual call to the search, that you're building things in the wrong order.

Comment: how would i go around it then? i'm trying to learn this by my self, so alot of this is obviously unclear to me at this point.

Comment: Well, opinions will differ, but personally I like to get it working first, and make it nice afterwards.

Comment: oh yea, that totally makes sense. However as a rookie in this, i tend to do the more tangible things first, its always nice with a protip, i will keep that in mind :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the textbox in your html and show/hide it using jQuery or you can create the textbox element dynamically and then append it to your search form container.

```
$("#searchContainer").append('<input id="searchBox" name="txtSearch" type="text">');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can i make a default text in the box that dissapears when the user clicks to type? would this be right to do, taking into consideration that this is going to be grabbed by another function in c# for the actual search?

Comment: Yes, you should add a placeholder attribute to the input tag. for example `<input id="searchBox" name="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="type here...">`  And about the actual search I should say that this is right because the search form will submit!

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have to append an input. But first you have to append a Form and set the attributes and then append your input to the form.

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "GET");
form.setAttribute("action", "#");         
form.setAttribute("target", "_self");
var input= document.createElement("input");              
input.setAttribute("name", "");
input.setAttribute("value", "");
form.appendChild(input);
document.body.appendChild(form);
```

Change the last code of mine to append it to the desired place.

Comment: thank you for the answer. As i like simplicity in my jquery code, i can more easily understand what Arash DaneshAraste is doing in his above example. Would that be equally as correct?

Comment: His code is right too assuming that you have a form tag to handle to action of the input. but If you don't have a form, you have to append it (make it the parent element of the input) whether in html directly or append it using jquery.

Comment: But i guess the form element would be <input> in this case am i right?

Comment: Inputs are just some passive elements and need a <form action="#" type="post"></form> tag to be inside of. the form does the query by sending the data to the address mentioned in 'action' attribute. it's necessary.